Qiskit error: too many subscripts in einsum when calling DensityMatrix.evolve(Operator)
Minimal details: My density matrix is of dims=(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)). I want to use DensityMatrix.evolve(qc) to evolve this DM with a quantum circuit qc.
Below is the code to reproduce this error:
#Build the circuit
c_A = QuantumRegister(4,'c_A')
qc_A = QuantumCircuit(c_A)
qc_A.h(c_A[0])
qc_A.h(c_A[3])
qc_A.cx(c_A[3],c_A[2])
qc_A.cx(c_A[0],c_A[1])
qc_A.cx(c_A[0],c_A[2])
qc_A.cx(c_A[0],c_A[3])

c_B = QuantumRegister(4,'c_B')
qc_B = QuantumCircuit(c_B)
qc_B.h(c_B[0])
qc_B.h(c_B[3])
qc_B.cx(c_B[3],c_B[2])
qc_B.cx(c_B[0],c_B[1])
qc_B.cx(c_B[0],c_B[2])
qc_B.cx(c_B[0],c_B[3])


c_C = QuantumRegister(8,'c_C')
qc_C = QuantumCircuit(c_C)
qc_C.h(c_C[0])
qc_C.h(c_C[1])
qc_C.h(c_C[2])
qc_C.h(c_C[6])
qc_C.cx(c_C[0],c_C[4])
qc_C.cx(c_C[1],c_C[5])
qc_C.cx(c_C[6],c_C[7])
qc_C.cx(c_C[2],c_C[3])
qc_C.cx(c_C[0],c_C[1])
qc_C.cx(c_C[1],c_C[2])
qc_C.cx(c_C[2],c_C[0])
qc_C.cx(c_C[1],c_C[6])
qc_C.cx(c_C[6],c_C[0])
qc_C.cx(c_C[0],c_C[1])

c_M = QuantumRegister(16,'c_M') 
a_M = QuantumRegister(2,'a')
qc_init_ABC = QuantumCircuit(c_M,a_M)
qc_init_ABC.compose(qc_C, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], inplace=True)
qc_init_ABC.compose(qc_A, [8, 9, 10, 11], inplace=True)
qc_init_ABC.compose(qc_B, [12, 13, 14, 15], inplace=True)
qc_init_ABC.draw('mpl')

qc_LS = QuantumCircuit(c_M, a_M)
qc_LS.cx(c_M[0], a_M[0])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[4], a_M[0])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[8], a_M[0])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[11], a_M[0])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[0], a_M[1])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[1], a_M[1])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[12], a_M[1])
qc_LS.cx(c_M[13], a_M[1])
qc_init_M = qc_init_ABC.compose(qc_LS)
qc_init_M.draw('mpl')

# calculate sv and take partial trace over ancillas
sv_total=Statevector.from_instruction(qc_init_M)
merged_state_DM = partial_trace(sv_total, qargs=[16,17])

# evolve with circuit
qc_op = QuantumCircuit(c_M)
qc_op.z(c_M[1])
qc_op.z(c_M[2])
qc_op.z(c_M[5])
qc_op.z(c_M[6])
merged_state_DM.evolve(qc_op)

I have already tried transpiling the circuit first (as per this suggestion) but that doesn't really help. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Your density matrix merged_state_DM  represents a state with 16 qubits, but your circuit qc_op only has 8 qubits.

Yes, I updated the code so qc_op has 16 qubits as well but I get the same error

It seems this is not a Qiskit issue but rather a limitation in the maximum number of indices the numpy.einsum function is capable of handling (max is 26, as described in this thread).
However, since your circuit is unitary, instead of computing the reduced density matrix first, and then evolve it through qc_op, you can simply append qc_op to your initialization circuit, and then compute the reduced density matrix. This way, you avoid using the evolve method.
So, right after defining qc_init_M, you could do something like this:
qc_init_and_op = qc_init_M.copy()
qc_init_and_op.append(qc_op,c_M)

sv_total = Statevector.from_instruction(qc_init_and_op)
merged_state_DM = partial_trace(sv_total, qargs=[16,17])

